# Linq Group by Complex Type of List

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do a Linq GroupBy on some list objects of a list.

```
public class ItemDto
{

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<CondimentDto> Condiments { get; set; }
}

public class CondimentDto
{
    public CondimentDto(int ItemId, string productName, decimal originalPrice)
    {
        ItemId = ItemId;
        ProductName = productName;
        OriginalPrice = originalPrice;

    }
    public int PosItemId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal OriginalPrice { get; set; }

}
```

Here is list example.

```
var items = new List<ItemDto>();

items.Add(new ItemDto(){ItemId = 1, ProductName = "Steak", Condiments = new List<CondimentDto>{new CondimentDto(11, "Mayonez", 1)}});
items.Add(new ItemDto() { ItemId = 1, ProductName = "Steak", Condiments = new List<CondimentDto> { new CondimentDto(11, "Mayonez", 1) } });
items.Add(new ItemDto() { ItemId = 1, ProductName = "Steak", Condiments = new List<CondimentDto> { new CondimentDto(11, "Hardal", 1) } });
```

Here is my LinQ Query;

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => new {item.ItemId, item.Condiments})
                  .Select(x=>new ItemDto
                  {
                     ItemId = x.Key,
                     ProductName = x.First().ProductName,
                     Condiments = x.First().Condiments,
                     Count = x.Count()

                  })
                  .ToList();
```

What I want to do is I want to group my list by ItemId and List of Condiments. The result that I expect is

```
{
  items[
    {
      "ItemId": 1,
      "ProductName": "Steak",
      "Condiments": [
        {
          "ItemId": 11,
          "Name": "Mayonez",
          "Price": 1
        }
      ],
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "ItemId": 1,
      "ProductName": "Steak",
      "Condiments": [
        {
          "ItemId": 11,
          "Name": "Hardal",
          "Price": 1
        }
      ],
      "Count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

As a result there are two same list item that's why it has to be grouped and count is 2. And one different item which is condiment is Hardal. It's separate and count is 1.

Is it possible two group by a list object? By the way condiments can be null. Then it should only group by Id.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if an item has more than one condiment?  Should it only be grouped with items with the same set of condiments?  In the case of just one you could do the grouping with `item.Condiments?.FirstOrDefault()` (note that groups null and empty lists together).

Comment: Yes there are more than one condiment. In that case other item condiments also has to be more than one condiment otherwise it will be different from each other. It should be include same condiments. It should be same than i can count them.

Comment: I think first group by ItemId then compare Condimets List but i couldn't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two `IEqualityComparer<T>` classes here. One for comparing if two `CondimentDto` objects are equal and one for comparing if two `List<CondimentDto>` are equal. We pass the `CondimentComparer` to [`SequenceEqual()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) to determine if two lists are equal, and we pass `ItemDtoComparer` to [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) to group `ItemDto` objects from the main `items` list. We have to also create our own `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` to determine the equality.

```
public class CondimentComparer : IEqualityComparer<CondimentDto>
{
    public bool Equals(CondimentDto x, CondimentDto y)
    {
        // If all the properties match, then its equal
        return x.PosItemId == y.PosItemId && 
               x.ProductName == y.ProductName && 
               x.OriginalPrice == y.OriginalPrice;
    }

    // Get all hashcodes from object properties using XOR
    // Might be better ways to do this
    public int GetHashCode(CondimentDto obj)
    {
        return obj.PosItemId.GetHashCode() ^ 
               obj.ProductName.GetHashCode() ^
               obj.OriginalPrice.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class ItemDtoComparer : IEqualityComparer<ItemDto>
{
    public bool Equals(ItemDto x, ItemDto y)
    {

        // If two condiments are null, then just compare ItemId
        if (x.Condiments == null && y.Condiments == null)
        {
            return x.ItemId == y.ItemId;
        }

        // If one is null and the other is not, can't possiblly be equal
        else if (x.Condiments == null && y.Condiments != null ||
                 x.Condiments != null && y.Condiments == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If we get here we have two normal objects
        // Compare two objects ItemId and lists of condiments
        return x.ItemId == y.ItemId &&
               x.Condiments.SequenceEqual(y.Condiments, new CondimentComparer());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ItemDto obj)
    {

        // If condiments list is null, just get the ItemId hashcode
        if (obj.Condiments == null)
        {
            return obj.ItemId.GetHashCode();
        }

        // Otherwise do the XOR of ItemId and the aggregated XOR of the condiment list properties
        return obj.ItemId.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Condiments.Aggregate(0, (a, c) => a ^ c.PosItemId.GetHashCode() ^ c.ProductName.GetHashCode() ^ c.OriginalPrice.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Then you can pass `ItemDtoComparer` to `Groupby`:

```
var result = items
    .GroupBy(item => item, new ItemDtoComparer()) // Pass ItemDtoComparer here
    .Select(grp => new ItemDto
    {
        ItemId = grp.Key.ItemId,
        ProductName = grp.Key.ProductName,
        Condiments = grp.Key.Condiments,
        Count = grp.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Demo on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PZg9WY)

**Note:** The above `GetHashCode()` implementations are XORing hashcodes. This is considered to not be best practice, and following the suggestions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-overriding-gethashcode/263416#263416) offer better alternatives to avoiding hash collisions. I just chose this method as its easy to remember and demo.

Comment: What if therare are more than one condiments ? This is only group firs condiment.

Comment: No, It can be different even there can be empty list of condiments. Itemdto can contains condiments or not. But it should be group by same element of itemdto